# How do I find the sign of V5A and V2VX in the mesh equations?

Tags: circuit-analysis, mesh-analysis

[image]

I do not understand how to know if V5A and V2VX is meant to be positive or negative in these equations. In the mesh 1, the current in going the opposite direction to the 5A current source and in equation (1) V5A is positive. However, in mesh 2 the current I2 is going the same direction as the 2VX current source and in equation 2 and V2VX is positive as well. Shouldn't V2VX be positive according to the logic used in mesh 1. So how can I know the sign of the voltage of current sources in mesh equations? I have always assumed that if the current in the loop is going the same direction as the current source, the voltage assumed for the current source should be positive in the equation. However this is not the case here .

Comment: A clockwise current \$I_1\$ equals an anticlockwise current of \$-I_1\$.

Answer (score 1):

Just to get some part numbers into the schematic, rather than only values (some of which are the same):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJpusl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I didn't draw in the mesh currents because I'll use the same ones you already have drawn out. (But I've used letters for the current and voltage supplies to avoid conflicting with any node numbering or mesh current numbering.)

I also chose (you can choose differently) to orient the +/- arrangement for the current sources such that the tip of the arrow is + and the tail of the arrow is -. That's my convention and it may differ from the choices made in the diagram you have. Keep it in mind.

Always starting (you don't have to, I am) with the lower left-hand corner of each loop and following the loop arrow as the direction to proceed around the loop:

$$\begin{align*}
\underset{\text{starting}}{0\:\text{V}}&&+\overset{\text{+20 V}}{V_{_\text{A}}}-\underset{\text{voltage drop}}{R_1\cdot I_1}-V_{_\text{IA}}&=\underset{\text{ending}}{0\:\text{V}}
\\\\
\underset{\text{starting}}{0\:\text{V}}&&+V_{_\text{IA}}-\underset{\text{voltage drop}}{R_2\cdot \left(I_2-I_4\right)}+V_{_\text{IB}}&=\underset{\text{ending}}{0\:\text{V}}
\\\\
\underset{\text{starting}}{0\:\text{V}}&&-V_{_\text{IB}}-\underset{\text{voltage drop}}{R_3\cdot \left(I_3-I_4\right)}-\underset{\text{voltage drop}}{R_4\cdot I_3}&=\underset{\text{ending}}{0\:\text{V}}
\\\\
\underset{\text{starting}}{0\:\text{V}}&&-\overset{\text{+10 V}}{V_{_\text{B}}}-\underset{\text{voltage drop}}{R_5\cdot I_4}-\underset{\text{voltage drop}}{R_3\cdot \left(I_4-I_3\right)}-\underset{\text{voltage drop}}{R_2\cdot \left(I_4-I_2\right)}&=\underset{\text{ending}}{0\:\text{V}}
\end{align*}$$

That's four equations and six unknowns. So we need these additional facts:

$$\begin{align*}
I_2-I_1&=I_{_\text{A}}
\\\\
I_2-I_3&=I_{_\text{B}}=2\:\mho\cdot V_{_\text{X}}=-2\:\mho\cdot R_5\cdot I_4
\end{align*}$$

Let's pause. Remember that I arbitrarily chose to assign a voltage polarity to the current sources? You can just do that. Once you make that assessment, you only need to stay true to it.

So let's get back to your questions. The polarity of the current source voltage ***must*** be applied consistently at all times. It does ***not*** change just because the current mesh loop you are considering points one way or another. Ignore the current mesh loop direction. It's irrelevant. Just assign a fixed voltage polarity to your current sources and apply your choices consistently for each loop.